# Where to save files in tomcat

Tags: java, image, web-services, tomcat

I have a java webservice that uploads files

I want to save the file locally - which i succeeded

and provide a url in order to display the file (image) inside a webpage later

however, I can't return "C:/path/to/saved/file.jpg"

how do I convert the path of my file to a url displayable in a webpage that is addressed to by localhost:8080/webappname/        ?

Comment: Your web service will handle any request to some path. You just stream the bytes in the response.

Comment: how do i display a byte[] in a webpage?

Comment: @LenaBru, again on client side you need to convert back into image and display it.

Comment: isnt there a simpler way?

Answer (score 0):

Ok the following code shows a simple JSP that does the job. BUT remember, this should be used only to try the approach. You should do this in a Servlet, not a JSP:

```
<%@ page import="java.net.*"%>
<%@ page import="java.io.*"%>
<%@ page import="java.lang.String"%>
<%@ page import="java.net.*"%>
<%@ page import="java.lang.Object"%>
<html>
<body>

<%
response.setContentType("image/jpeg");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=stuff" + ".jpg");

URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com/images/logos/ps_logo2.png");
URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();

BufferedOutputStream outs = new BufferedOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());
int len;               
byte[] buf = new byte[1024]; 
while ((len = stream.read(buf)) > 0)   
{  
    outs.write(buf, 0, len);    
}                  
outs.close(); 
%>

</body>
</html>
```

See, the approach is to write the content directly to the page, of course configuring the headers properly.

REgards